# What controls lid switch settings in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, dell, lid

I've just switched from the usual Unity Ubuntu to Gnome on my Dell XPS 9550 after being convinced by the hype, and frustrated by the litany of bugs I've spent years tolerating in Unity.

In my long, LONG list of new and inexplicable problems resulting from this, I'm having problems with getting the lid close switch to actually work.

What is it doing:

I dont even **know**.

In Settings>Power, it's set to "Blank Screen: 5 minutes" with "Automatic suspend" set entirely to "Off". Of course, its does none of things. Screen stays on, except on battery where it shuts itself down after what I think is about 30 minutes. Not hibernate, not standby, full shutdown, with 60% battery left. Bye bye, 3 hours of editing.

In "Tweak Tools>Power", on both battery and AC, it is set to "Blank" when lid is closed. "Don't Suspend on Lid close" is turned On. So, naturally, shutting the lid invokes Suspend. Unless on battery, in which case it does nothing. Screen stays on even when closed.  Change either option to something other than 'Blank', has zero effect - screen perma-on. Unless you turn off "Don't Suspend on Lid close", in which case closing the lid causes a suspend, no matter any other settings. Unless on battery. In which case it shuts down.

In Dconf Editor (3 control interfaces?? Seriously????) under "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power", *sleep-inactive* on both ac-type and battery are set to "nothing" , and both lid close setting are set to "blank". But none of this changes anything. Clearly. That would make this 3rd  control panel actually useful.

And now I've just found another thread that says I need to edit "/etc/systemd/logind.conf" ?????? I've uncommented BOTH 'HandleLidSwitch' terms and STILL the complex and unusual abilty to have my screen turn off when it closes​ eludes me.

Booting into a fresh LiveCD does nothing different. This problem exists out of the box. How is it that a supposedy reliable and stable OS has SO MANY different, fragmented control points for something as fundamental and simple as a lid close action, NONE of which actually control said hardware? Windows had this stuff sorted by XP.

Can ANYONE please tell just what is in control of lid switch behavior in Gnome, and/or how to make the usual controls actually do their damn job?

Comment: Same problem on my XPS13 since leaving unity. :(

Answer (score 0):

5 years later there is an app simply called "Tweaks".

The first option under general allows you to turn off **suspend when laptop lid is closed**. This is what you want to use when your laptop is connected to an external screen.

[image: the setting I changed]

How to install tweaks on Ubuntu: https://linuxhint.com/install-tweak-tool-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: Dunno who deleted my last comment, but this still doesn't even do anything.

Comment: It does work, this is the setting I used to fix the problem for myself when I found there was no answer to your question. If you want help from random strangers who aren't paid to help you, you're going to have to be more descriptive and more kind.